# How do I set a template for CubeCart?

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system

I'm a php developer and currently working on a project in which I'm required to change the layout of a web page created using CubeCart.  I've never worked before with CubeCart. I've created a template but don't konw where to place my stylesheet and other things on server as there are a lot of folders and files. This is very confusing. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: you would be better of asking on the CubeCart support forum

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through their site, I found [this page](https://support.cubecart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2/0/how-can-i-completely-change-the-look-of-cubecart) on editing the look/feel.  It seems you're looking for this folder: /public_html/store/skins .

It would be best to make a new folder in there to store your working template.  Copy all the default skin files into it and edit those.

To turn it on, go into the store admin and then [Store Config] -> [General Settings] then the [Styles and Misc] section.  There should be a drop down for Store Skin - change it to yours.